# illegal start of expression in line 22

Tags: java

I am a beginner,I'm having problem with my very first code.I just trying to solve coupling shaft alignment.

It says, "illegal start of expression".Can someone help me with this problem? thanks

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Front {

     public static void main(String []args){

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         Double A = input.nextDouble();
         Double B = input.nextDouble();
         Double C = input.nextDouble();
         Double S = input.nextDouble();
         Double M = input.nextDouble();             

         Double F = B / A * (S-M)/2 - S/2;

         System.out.println("The front foot is: " + F +); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Remove the trailing `+` in `...F +);`.

Answer (score 2):

You missed an operand after your last `+` in `System.out.println("The front foot is: " + F +);`

Another option is to use formatted output:

```
System.out.printf("The front foot is: %f\n", F.floatValue());
```

Comment: thanks! now i can continue. thanks